# How to mount storage by desktop shortcut?

Tags: mount, shortcut-keys

I want to mount by click to shortcut on desktop.
My shortcut:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Terminal=true
    Icon=mate-panel-launcher
    Exec=sshfs 192.168.10.10:/home/www-data /home/stager/mnt/home.www-data
    Name=sshfs 192.168.10.10
```

On initiate this, terminal opened, password asked. But mounting not happens.

Alternatively, in terminal:
`$ sshfs 192.168.10.10:/home/www-data /home/stager/mnt/home.www-data`
works as expected.

How to mount by desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

With the shortcut, the terminal opens, the mount is executed, then the terminal closes and accordingly also closes all processes that were launched under it. You need to keep that terminal open in the background, or try approaches involving `disown` or `nohup` to detach the process from the current shell. You will still be able to terminate the mount using the file manager.

Instead, you can consider using the native feature of your file manager to create the connection and make a bookmark for one click access from within the file manager.

Comment: I've already told you - you're wrong. It is easy to make sure of this.

Comment: So is this a duplicate question then? Did you try keeping the terminal open to confirm that is not the issue? It would work with Terminal=False. The problem then moves to: how to supply the password.

Comment: You may be able to help out here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361141/sshfs-umount-after-close-terminal This user has the problem that the sshfs connection breaks when closing the terminal.